# MvvmCross resource loader plugin

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, stream, resources, mvvmcross

I try to load a XML resource with the MvxResourceLoader Plugin available over nuget.

Steps I made:

1. Downloaded the Plugin to the PCL and the Windows Phone Project.
2. Injected the plugin into my viewmodel. (_loader)
3. Added this line:

   _loader.GetResourceStream("Assets/Suggestions.xml", delegate(Stream stream) {...});
4. Added resource to my Windows Phone project under the correct path and set to Resource.

Result:

The stream is always null. Tried also different Versions of the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what your exact situation is, but there are a couple of working demos which use the Resource plugin - and you could compare your projects against these (although these may still be stuck in Winph7 to Winph8 handover so may need some love...):

- Babel - JsonLocalisation - see https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/Babel
- Conference - the sessions are loaded from Json resources - see https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/Sample%20-%20CirriousConference

Also there's some documentation available on: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-plugins#wiki-resourceloader

For WindowsPhone, `GetResourceStream` is implemented in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Plugins/Cirrious/ResourceLoader/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.ResourceLoader.WindowsPhone/MvxWindowsPhoneResourceLoader.cs#L19 - which loads the content as:

```
var streamInfo = System.Windows.Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(resourcePath, UriKind.Relative));
```

So, do your resources load when just using this `System.Windows` call? If they do, then the plugin should work too.